# Silver badge on Meta

Tags: support, per-site-meta, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

You get the 925 badge for getting a silver badge.  Do you still get the badge of you got that silver badge on the Meta site for a particular SE site?

N.B.: I am not talking about Meta.SE, I'm talking about per-site metas like [Meta Mechanics](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com) or [Meta Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.stackexchange.com).